# php enquiry form- Could not send message. Error

Tags: php

Once i click on submit button it Showing error : Could not send message. Please Help thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    $emailTo = "xyz@gmail.com";//change this to the email address which should receive the form data
    $redirect_to = 'contact.html';           // Page to show after form is processed

    /*  
        NOTE: do not change anything below this
    */
    if( isset($_POST['maximus']) ) {
        //honey pot detection
        if( $_POST['maximus'] != '' ) {
            die('Bad spam bot!!');
        }

        $message = "";
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $val ) {
            if( $field != 'maximus' ) {
                $message .= $field . " : ". $val . "\n";
            }   
        }
        $subject = $_POST['theSubject'];
        //send the email
        if( mail($emailTo, $subject, $message) ) {
            header("Location: $redirect_to");
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Could not send message.";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please provide more than just a code snippet. What is your problem? What question do you need answered?

Answer (score 0):

If `mail()` is failing, then you need to find out why. You can check the PHP error log, or you can get the error message that `mail(...)` returned by calling [error_get_last()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php).

```
if( mail($emailTo, $subject, $message) ) {
    header("Location: $redirect_to");
    exit;
} else {
    echo "Could not send message.";
    print_r(error_get_last());
}
```

Comment: Right, but it should be giving you a more detailed error at this point.

Comment: Its not showing any details about error. just a message of Could not send message error.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the email sending was failed. If you are trying in localhost, sending mail can fail for not having mail setup. If in server, contact your host provider.